Efficient 63-bit long computation of (a*b)/c in Java
I would like to compute (a*b)/c in Java in the most efficient way where:

a, b and c are unsigned long values (guaranteed to fit in 63 bits, i.e. with zero sign bit)
The result is also guaranteed to fit in 63 bits
The product (a*b) is likely to overflow with regular long multiplication

What is the most efficient way to calculate this? I have a working solution with BigInteger conversions but am looking for something faster (minimal clock cycles, preferably zero memory allocation)
I have heard about premature optimization, and I have determined that this optimization is worthwhile.

@0x150: Oh. I'm pretty sure that's a typo, and it was supposed to be a*b.

Thanks I corrected typo, of course it is (a*b) that is likely to overflow

please define "most efficient" - faster, less memory, easier to understand/implement,  less code, ...

As someone once said, premature optimization is the root of all evil. Until you can verifyably prove that this computation is what's making the program slow, I wouldn't worry about it.

@0x150 I've determined it's worthwhile and I've heard that expression a million times, it isn't really helpful. Looking for a specific answer to the specific question, also to help others who may encounter the same issue.

@0x150 I suggest you look up what Don Knuth actually said. This is only a partial quotation from it, and a much misused one. The rest of it is important as well. And this is exactly the kind of code that may need tuning to the Nth degree.

Would it be viable to implement the method natively in C or C++ using a 128-bit type in those languages, then invoke it in Java using JNI?

I'm looking for a pure Java implementation @jsheeran (hopefully one that is pretty close to C/C++ performance once the JIT does its job :-) )

Mathematically, (a*b)/c is equal to both (a/c)*b and (b/c)*a. The most accurate result only using integer division will be dividing the larger of a and b by c, then multiplying by the other:
long result = a > b ? (a / c * b) : (b / c * a);

While this will be as fast as you can get it, its accuracy is limited by the truncation of the remainder of the division. You can simulate rounding, thus doubling the accuracy at only a tiny cost in performance, by adding half of c before the division:
long result = a > b ? ((a + c/2) / c * b) : ((b + c/2) / c * a);

